# Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Failed to run aapt dump badging:

Tags: android

**This question has been asked before but none of the answers worked for me. That's why i am posting it again**

I have not  been able to upload any apk file to google player for the last one month, after the fresh installation in my computer.

Following is my test case:

I created a dummy hello world project, when I tried to export a Signed Application Package, I got lint errors in appcompact_v7.  (Never had this issue before)

This is one of the error.

Error: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix.

Location: abc_search_dropdown_dark.xml:19 in drawable(appcompact_v7)

I ignored all the lint warning and exported a Signed Application Package, but i am unable to upload the apk file to google player. I get the following message.
"Upload failed
Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded"

I am using windows 7.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Android SDK Tools 24.0.2

Android SDK Platform-tools 21

Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.2

Android 5.0.1 (API 21), SDK Platform 2

ADT-23.0.4

Now i am totally lost and don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I solved this problem by moving from Eclipse to Android Studio and every thing is working fine.